# What is wrong with my sed regex (works in egrep, but not sed)?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, clojure, grep

I wanted to remove type hints from my Clojure source codes, so I tried:

```
echo "(def ^Integer a 1)" | egrep '\^\w+ '
```

And it successfully matches the type hint.

Next, I tried:

```
echo "(def ^Integer a 1)" | sed s/\^\w+//g
```

however `sed` does not replace the type hint with empty.

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Plenty, sed uses a much different syntax than egrep. What are you trying to achieve? Trying to remove ^Integer? or all instances of ^word regardless of what word is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the regex in `'` and also escape the `+`:

```
echo "(def ^Integer a 1)" | sed 's/\^\w\+//g'
```

Comment: @HowardGuo it's very kind of you to accept my answer, but if Zack's answer works for you, I think he deserves it a lot more - seeing his solution is portable and provides a lot of explanation.

Comment: @m.buettner I don't begrudge you the checkmark, only what version of sed is that in which `\w` works?

Comment: @Zack, I just tried it out on my remote Unix server (I'm not much of a Unix guy, to be honest), but here is what `sed` claims its version is: `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: mine is sed 4.2.1 as well ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Nearly all versions of `sed` implement what are called POSIX *basic* regular expressions, not *extended* regular expressions.  The 'e' in `egrep` stands for ... extended.  Guess which kind of regexp it implements. `:)`  One of the big differences between basic and extended regexps is that `+` is only a metacharacter in an extended regexp.  *Some* implementations of basic RE accept `\+` with the same meaning, but you cannot portably rely on `sed` supporting that.

Moreover, `\w` is not even part of POSIX extended regexp syntax; it's a Perl-ism which has since been widely adopted (e.g. by Python and Javascript) but is AFAIK not officially standardized anywhere.

The construct you need here is

```
echo "(def ^Integer a 1)" | sed 's/\^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*//g'
```

No, there is no shorter way to write that portably.